# Can I access an object in C++ other than using an expression?

Tags: c++, expression, language-lawyer, data-manipulation

According to C++03 3.10/1 *every expression is either an lvalue or an rvalue*. When I use `=` to assign a new value to a variable the variable name on the left of the assignment is an lvalue expression. And it looks like whatever I try to do with a variable it'll still use some expression.

Is there any way to manipulate a variable in C++ other than by using an expression?

Comment: +1: like the language-lawyer tag.

Comment: all value computation will involve expression. Type computations e.g. decltypes do not. But I am not sure if you are asking specifically about variable manipulations and hence value computation

Comment: Sounds a bit like doing something without doing something.

Comment: @Christian Rau: Maybe. An answer like "no, there's no other way" would be just fine.

Comment: does prefix increment count as an expression?

Comment: @Evgeni Yes, it has a type and a value (not sure if that are valid definition criteria though, but prefix increment is definitely an expression).

Comment: @ChristianRau What isn't, then?

Comment: @Evgeni Don't know, I guess everything is an expression somehow, but in the end I'm not that well-versed in the depths of the language standard and its terminology (which is why I still up-voted this question and don't dare to write a trivial *"no"*-answer).

Comment: @ChristianRau I thought beeing an expression had something to do with "beeing evaluated", for example having at least a `=`. Thats why I considered prefix `++` to be an exception, because the variable is logically only incremented, but not really read (at least not on the "C++-level")

Comment: @Evgeni I don't think evaluation implies having a `=` inside. In fact `1 + 2` is an arithmetic expression, too, since it can be evaluated (to `3` of type `int`), and so can `++a`, having the type and value of `a` after the increment. In fact just writing `a` is an expression with the value and type of `a` (or an lvalue reference to `a`?).

Comment: @ChristianRau You're right. My aplogies to sharptooth, but the longer I think about it,the sillier the question becomes

Comment: _Real_ programmers use a magnetized needle and a steady hand. (http://xkcd.com/378/)

Comment: Heck, `1` is an expression, you don't need `1+2`.

Comment: Does inline asm count as an expression? :>

Comment: @JonasWielicki, an `asm` block is a declaration, but you put string literal(s) inside it, and a literal is an expression.

Answer (score 2):

The only way would be through a statement, yet not via an expression which is part of such a statement. An example would be a definition, `std::string x;`. This calls the default ctor on `x`. But does this count as a manipulation to you?

There aren't that many other statements, actually. Loop control statements cannot change objects themselves other than via side effects of the loop control expressions. `goto`, `break` and `continue` can't do it at all. `throw` is an expression and `catch()` can't change anything, so that pair is also irrelevant. I don't think there's any other non-expression-statement.

Comment: Hm, ``catch`` will assign the exception value to a variable if you ask it to do so, won't it?

Comment: Yes, but you would need `C-x M-c M-butterfly` to spontaneously generate an exception in that case.  Otherwise you need an expression to cause the `throw`.

Comment: @JonasWielicki: No it won't, not in the strict sense of the word. It _initializes_ a new variable. It can't modify (assign to) an existing variable.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the value of a variable without using an expression, but you can't really choose what value it gets.  The way I read appendix A of the C++11 standard (the language grammar), a **declaration** is not an expression.  If you write `int a;` at function scope, `a` will be assigned an indeterminate value.  If you write it at file scope, `a` will be assigned the value 0.  But you can't assign it a value or pass constructor arguments because the act of doing so involves an expression.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it answers your question strictly but you can manipulate a variable indirectly. E.g.:

```
int a;
int *pA = &a;
*pA = 5;
```

Here the value of `a` is changed but without any expression involving `a`. The expression involves only `pA`.

Other than that, there might be side effects of unrelated operations that result in variable change, either intentional or not (such as memory corruption that unintentionally changes some variable).